# Select and unselect checkboxes

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

i have a list of Checkbox's .

> checkbox1,checkbox2....

i want to  uncheck  the checkbox if its is checked and vice  versa.Is there any way to do this.

Comment: I think you need to explain your question in a bit more detail. At least, I hope the question needs more detail.

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach (CheckBox cb in cbList) {
  cb.Checked = !cb.Checked;
}
```

Comment: I like the KISS principle :=)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (CheckBox1.Checked == true)
    {
    CheckBox1.Checked = false
    }
    else
    {
    CheckBox1.Checked = true
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're working in ASP.NET, WPF, WinForms, ...

But it's as easy as check if checkbox is checked, then uncheck, and viceversa.

Or you can implement an extension method like:

```
public static class CheckboxExtensions
{
     public static void ToggleChecked(this CheckBox some) 
     {
           if(some != null) 
           {
                  if(some.Checked)
                  {
                        some.Checked = false;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                        some.Checked = true;
                  }
           }
    }
}
```

... And your actual code will look like this:

```
chkSome.ToggleChecked();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
checkBox1.Checked = !checkBox1.Checked;
```